# ReactJs: Dynamic route shows the empty props

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom, react-props, is-empty

This is my first react application. I am trying to fetch the `uuid` from the `props` object but it always returns an empty object. However, the pages are loading without any error.

I googled for the solution and found a few, but none of them solved this problem.

App.js

```js
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

import Layout from "./layouts/Backend";
import Language from "./pages/languages/index";
import LanguageCreate from "./pages/languages/create";
import LanguageEdit from "./pages/languages/edit";

...

export default () => {
   return (
      <BrowserRouter>
         <Routes>
            <Route path="/" exact element={<Layout />}>
               <Route path="/">
                  <Route path="/" element={<Language />} />
                  <Route path={"/language/create"} element={<LanguageCreate />} />
                  <Route path={"/language/edit/:uuid"} element={<LanguageEdit />} />
               </Route>

               ...
            </Route>
         </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
   );
};
```

pages/languages/edit.jsx

```js
import React from "react";

export default class LanguageEdit extends React.Component {
   state = {
      uuid: null,
   };

   componentDidMount() {
      // this.setState({
      //    uuid: this.props.match.params.uuid,
      // });

      console.log(this.props);
   };

   render() {
      return <div>Language Edit...</div>
   }
};
```

Why is the `props` empty..?
What am I doing wrong..?

Comment: `this.props` is an "empty object" because no props are passed to `Languageedit`, as evidenced by the route: `element={<LanguageEdit />}`, e.g. no props were passed to the component. Also, just FYI in the component it is considered a React anti-pattern to store passed props into local state, just consume/reference the `uuid` param directly in the component.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try in below way

**old way**

`<Route path="/language/edit/:uuid" render={(props) => <LanguageEdit {...props} />} />`

or

**Router dom v6 way**

`<Route path="/language/edit/:uuid" element={<LanguageEdit render={(props) => ({ ...props })} />} />`